# Smoothing Vector3.normalized?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a player inside of Unity 3D with a Character Controller, I got him all configured to walk, look around and such. So when using a normal vector3 the player starts of smoothly until it's at his max speed. When I don't normalize it, you can walk faster by pressing W and D/A at the same time, you go about 50% faster than normal. But when I normalize it, the player is immediately at it's max speed. Which looks very weird.

How would I do it so the player starts smoothed out before it's at it max speed?

Here's my full script, incase you need it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour {

    CharacterController cc;

    public float    baseSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float    mouseSensitivity = 1.0f;

    public bool     inverted = false;
    public bool     gravityOn = true;
    public bool     lockMouse = true;

    float           mouseRotX = 0,
                    mouseRotY = 0;

    float           curSpeed = 3.0f;
    float           invertion = 1.0f;
    float           gravitySpeed = 0;

    string          h = "Horizontal";
    string          v = "Vertical";



    void Start () {
        cc = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        if (lockMouse && Debug.isDebugBuild)
            Screen.lockCursor = true;

        if (!Debug.isDebugBuild)
            Screen.lockCursor = true;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {

        curSpeed = baseSpeed;

        if (inverted)
            invertion = -1.0f;
        else
            invertion = 1.0f;

        mouseRotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        mouseRotY -= invertion * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;;
        mouseRotY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseRotY, -90.0f, 90.0f);

        float forwardMovement = Input.GetAxis(v);
        float strafeMovement = Input.GetAxis(h);

        Vector3 speed = new Vector3(strafeMovement, 0, forwardMovement);
        speed = transform.rotation * speed;
        Debug.Log(speed.normalized);

        //Applying Gravity
        if (cc.isGrounded)
        {
            gravitySpeed = 0.0f;
        }
        else if (gravityOn)
        {

            if (gravitySpeed >= 20.0f)
            {
                gravitySpeed = 20.0f;
            }

            if (cc.isGrounded == false)
            {
                gravitySpeed += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            cc.Move(new Vector3(0, gravitySpeed, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        //Applying movement and rotation.
        cc.Move(speed.normalized * curSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Rotate(0, mouseRotX, 0);
        Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseRotY, 0 ,0); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read what normalize actually does?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking how to smooth it out.

Comment: Since your question is: how to slowly increase curSpeed -either implement real acceleration or simply interpolate between initial and max value over some time.

Comment: Note: smoothing normalized vector phrase sounds very strange as you don't seem to want change of direction and length of normalized vector is always one - so nothing left that can be changed.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what it's called.. Acceleration! Thank you, I think I can get a little further with that.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want to get is uniformly accelerated motion.

You need something like this:

```
Vector3 _speed = Vector3.zero;

const float KDrag = 0.25f;

void FixedUpdate () 
{

float forwardMovement = Input.GetAxis(v);
float strafeMovement = Input.GetAxis(h);

Vector3 acceleration = cc.transform.right * strafeMovement + cc.transform.forward * forwardMovement;

_speed += acceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
_speed -= _speed * KDrag * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

cc.Move( _speed  * Time.fixedDeltaTime );
}
```